# Find and Replace event handler in visual studio

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2010, replace

How do i use Find and Replace Regular expression to find and replace event handlers in visual studio that end with the same name.

for example

```
GridView1_DataBound
CheckBoxList1_DataBound
```

the format is [**some text**]_[**event name**]

i tried using *_DataBound and it says *Syntax Error in Pattern*

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
[^_\\"]+_[^\\"]+
```

Or use this and get the 1st group (**group1**).

```
[^\\"]+\\"([^_\\"]+_[^\\"]+)\\"
```

Comment: doesnt work. I am trying to find all events in the aspx markup that are written as OnDataBound="GridView1_DataBound". i just need the GridView1_DataBound part. so i need a regex like anything_DataBound or anything_OnTextChanged etc. Also anything here just means GridView1and not the whole preceding line.

Comment: Sorry, I modified my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
(\w[^_]+_\w+)
```

This should work for the given context. (We are not trying to validate text; we know the target text is an event handler name with sometext_sometext)